# Time Delay in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, timedelay

i want to introduce a 3 hour delay between two consecutive lines in my VB script code.

I am using the following code snippet for this:

```
WScript.Sleep 10800000
```

But I think the code is stopping for a long time, much more than 3 hours. I used 10800000 as i read time is given in milliseconds.

Please let me know my mistake and the correct way to achieve this.
Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
timeout = DateAdd("h", 3, Now)
Do Until Now > timeout
  WScript.Sleep 200
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

**Important** This solution was provided because question was tagged [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) at the beginning.

I will give you different option. I imagine you have something like this at the moment:

```
Sub MyCurrentSub()
    Dim A
    A = 10
    'wait 3 hour here and...
    '...after 3 hours do other part of the sub
    MsbBox A
End Sub
```

During waiting time, even if you use different option to wait (like `Do...Loop`) your Excel application will be limited, at least partially will not work as usually.

I would do it in this way, by creating and calling different Sub at the right moment:

```
Public A
Sub MyNewSub_1()
    A = 10
    Appication.OnTime Now + TimeValue("03:00:00"), "MyNewSub_2"
End Sub
'now you can use your Excel as usually...
Sub MyNewSub_2()
    MsgBox A
End Sub
```

You will get the same result, Excell will be free for you to use for 3 hours during waiting time. The only think you need to remember is to- **DO NOT QUIT APPLICATION**. If you Quit Excel it will 'forget' to call `MyNewSub_2`.

Comment: this tip is for VBA as stated in question tags. I don't know how to do it in VBScript...